# nx build command failed with TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'cloud')

Tags: debugging, next.js, monorepo, nrwl-nx

I am trying to run `nx build` it was working fine, but now it stopped working.
below are the logs

```
/vercel/path0/node_modules/@nrwl/nx-cloud/lib/nx-cloud-tasks-runner.js:20
    const noCloud = nxArgs['cloud'] === false;
                          ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'cloud')
    at nxCloudTasksRunner (/vercel/path0/node_modules/@nrwl/nx-cloud/lib/nx-cloud-tasks-runner.js:20:27)
    at /vercel/path0/node_modules/@nrwl/workspace/src/tasks-runner/run-command.js:85:37
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (/vercel/path0/node_modules/@nrwl/workspace/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:115:62)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error seems to be happening with `@nrwl/nx-cloud@latest`. Try downgrading @nrwl/nx-cloud. For me version 13.1.6 works good.

Comment: As of Nov 18, `14.6.0` works well as well.