# TypeError: Cannot read property 'cloud' of undefined

Tags: angular, nrwl-nx

I upgraded the nx version from 12.10.0 to 14.1.9 especially to upgrade the angular version from 12.2.15 - 13.3.9. The migration worked correctly but when I do `yarn nx run {home}:serve`.

I see this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'cloud' of undefined
> at nxCloudTasksRunner (/Users/ghoshi/Desktop/Work/Content-Platform/vcap-platform-applications/node_modules/@nrwl/nx-cloud/lib/nx-cloud-tasks-runner.js:20:27)
> at /Users/ghoshi/Desktop/Work/Content-Platform/vcap-platform-applications/node_modules/nx/src/tasks-runner/run-command.js:78:37
> at Generator.next ()
> at fulfilled (/Users/ghoshi/Desktop/Work/Content-Platform/vcap-platform-applications/node_modules/nx/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:114:62)
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
> error Command failed with exit code 1.
> info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

Comment: You can try to remove your nodemodules directory and run npm install.

Comment: Find a solution?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73783973/nx-build-command-failed-with-typeerror-cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-rea

There is solution to downgrade to `@nrwl/nx-cloud@13.1.6`

Answer (score 8):

I had a problem similar to yours. I even tried deleting the `node_modules` folder and installing again, but it didn't fix the error... In my case, I solved it by updating the `taskRunnerOptions` setting in the `nx.json` file, and switched from cloud to runner default workspace as follows:

```
"tasksRunnerOptions": {
    "default": {
      "runner": "@nrwl/workspace/tasks-runners/default",
      "options": {
        "cacheableOperations": ["build", "lint", "test", "e2e"]
      }
    }
  },
```

Comment: Thanks that seem to have worked

Comment: Well, this would mean not using the cache?

Comment: Did not work. Still the same issue for me

Answer (score 4):

I found the issue, It has to do with the version of NX cloud that is compatible with NX 14.1.9.
The nxcloud version comes with the migration is 14.6 while the working version is 14.0. So once I downgraded to 14.0. NX cloud starts working again.

Comment: Downgrading `npm i @nrwl/nx-cloud@14.0 --save-exact` worked for me. Thanks

Comment: Did not work. Still the same issue for me